# Unable to add font awesome insid a Button using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, font-awesome

I have the following button:-

```
<button id="show" style="background:#4d9b84" class=" btn btn-primary">Click here to learn more</button>
```

and i wrote the following jQuery to change the button's text from "Click here to learn more" to an upper arrow using font awesome, as follow:-

```
$("#show").click(function () {
                    $("#show").html("<i class=\"fa fa - arrow - up\" aria-hidden=\"true\" style=\"color:#2ebdbe!important\"></i>");
                }
            });
```

but i got an empty button when i click on the button as follow:-

[image]

any advice please, on how i can add a font awesome icon inside a button using jQuery?
Thanks

Comment: `fa fa - arrow - up` should be `fa fa-arrow-up`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the spaces in the class name:

```
  $("#show").html("<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\" aria-hidden=\"true\" style=\"color:#2ebdbe!important\"></i>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in your class name it should be fa-arrow-up.